# Issues with Database

Tags: database, cache

If I update the prices, SKU's etc.. in admin they will reflect on the front end but the grid inside admin still shows the old data.

I have tried re-indexing and optimising the database but this doesnt resolve the problem.

Could it be todo with code cache? Recently upgraded to Magento 2.1.14

Comment: Do you have multiple stores?

Comment: No, there is just the one store. There were two store views but one was removed before launch (6 months ago)